# ScrollView does not show all content in react native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have a page with some Components. I am using scrollview to scroll through the page but some content does not show. Here is my code:

```
render() {
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
const {currentItem,callsData}=this.state;
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={CustomStyles.container}>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse',padding:10}}>
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <CustomText style={[CustomStyles.titleWhite]}>Sponsers</CustomText></View>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()} style={{marginLeft:20,padding:10,}}>
        <Icon name='md-arrow-round-back' color={'white'} size={32} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1,height:screenHeight}}>
    <View>
    {(this.state.done===1)?
    <View >
    <CustomText style={[CustomStyles.titleWhite,{alignSelf: 'center',}]}> {currentItem.title} </CustomText>
    <Image style={{width:'100%',height:'30%',resizeMode:'contain'}} source={{uri:Strings.imageUrl+ currentItem.image1}}/>
    <CustomText style={[{color:'white',lineHeight:24}]}>{currentItem.body}</CustomText>
    <Video source={{uri:currentItem.videoLink}}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
    controls={true}                              // Store reference
    onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
    onError={this.videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
    paused={true}
    style={{width:'100%',height:screenHeight/4,}} />
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}>
      <Icon />
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}>
      <CustomText style={CustomStyles.whiteTxt}>website: </CustomText>
      <CustomText style={{color:Colors.yellow,marginRight: 3}}>{currentItem.website}</CustomText>
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}>
    <CustomText style={CustomStyles.whiteTxt}>Address: </CustomText>
      <CustomText style={{color:Colors.yellow,marginRight: 3,}}>{currentItem.address}</CustomText>
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}>
    <CustomText style={[CustomStyles.whiteTxt,]}>Calls: </CustomText>
    <FlatList
    data={callsData}
    contentContainerStyle={{alignItems:'flex-end',marginRight:4}}
    keyExtractor={(index)=>index}
    renderItem={({item,index})=>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.renderCall(index)}>
      <CustomText style={{color:Colors.yellow}}>{item}</CustomText></TouchableOpacity>}
    />
    <View style={{flex:1}}/>
    </View>
    </View>

    :
    <ActivityIndicator/>}</View>
  </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
 }
```

EDIT: Here is CustomStyles.js, Colors file is just containing color codes:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../Values/Colors'
export default StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
    titleWhite:{
      color:'white',
      fontSize:18,margin:5
    },
  })
```

I also tried to use View instead of SafeAreaView but the problem did not solved. the bottom component does not show.
 help me please

Comment: Would you mind clarifying in a separate code block which part isn't showing? And could you show the CustomStyles object you're referencing?

Comment: Having issues on both Android and iOS?

Comment: @James I edit my post. Every Component that is out of screen height is not showing. It's different for display size

Comment: @user1872384 I just tested on Android

Comment: Try to use <> empty tag to replace the "parent" <view>

Comment: I did not undrestand where to use <>

Comment: So you mean the scroll view isn't scrolling?

Comment: No, a View component is above the ScrollView . The ScrollView Scroll as the size of this view. If I remove the height property of ScrollView, it does not Cover the whole page and also not scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in Image component height property. I change it from "percent" to number like this From:

```
height:'30%'
```

to

```
height:.3*screenHeight
```

And now the `ScrollView` work fine